# Prestashop index without shop

Tags: indexing, customization, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm implementing prestashop in my website but I don't want it to be only a prestashop page. The solution could be to create a folder to the shop and put PS inside, but I want to use some functionalities in the rest of the site, like user login and profile, shop-cart...

I've read that working with exceptions in modules can make this happen but I wonder if there's a way to implement some PS features without working with .tpl structures

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of Smarty templates? Some old modules just echo/return the HTML code from class functions, but it is quite messy and unreadable instead of using templates for HTML code.

Comment: Because smarty is messier for what I need. I just wanted to implement a shop to my web site, now I have to implement my website to the shop.

Comment: Prestashop view is based on Smarty template engine, if it doesn't fit your needs, what about another open-source platform? A lot of Prestashop modules is based on Smarty, if you try to avoid using them, you will run into several problems during implementation. What about Wordpress with some e-commerce plugin, etc.?